# How to include optional parameters in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

```
(function ( $ ) {
    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {
        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );
        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });
    };
}( jQuery ));
```

Taken from [Docs](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/) the above code shows how to make a simple jquery plugin. What if I only supply one of multiple parameters listed in a plugin that accepts multiple? Which ones are applied? 
If I have a plugin that can take multiple parameters, which ones will be applied in something like this: 
 `$.doStuff({color:"black"},{color:"blue"});` 
What set of options will be "extended" when only one set of parameters if supplied?
E.x. `$.doStuff({color:"black"});`

Comment: well, typically you won't have multiple parameters, instead you'll have one object with multiple properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call a function with more parameters than there are argument variables, and the function doesn't use the special `arguments` variable to access variable-length arguments, the extra parameters will be ignored.

So in your example:

```
$.greenify({color: "black"}, {color: "blue"});
```

the `options` variable will be set to `{color: "black"}`, and the `{color: "blue"}` parameter will be ignored.

Comment: And does that logic follow most cases? So if I have 5 parameters and the plugin accepts 6 the last one is ignored?

Comment: Yes. Doesn't that fit the description "more parameters than argument variables"?

Comment: I haven't slept in days. please excuse the brain farts. Thanks.